# Automatic archiving of log files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, logging

I look at my various log files, and I believe the operating system will periodically archive the log by appending a datestamp to it.

I've created some custom logs in my httpd.conf file, however, these do not have similar behavior.

How can I make my custom logs periodically be renamed with datestamps similar to the other logs?

httpd.conf

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/books/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/books/forwarded.log common_forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/books/access.log combined env=!dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/books/log combined

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/books/rewrite
    RewriteLogLevel 9
</IfModule>
```

logs

```
[root@devserver httpd]# pwd
/var/log/httpd
[root@devserver httpd]# ls -l
total 68100
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     8263 Dec 16 03:55 access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   594502 Nov 23 03:12 access_log-20141123
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   442241 Nov 30 01:46 access_log-20141130
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    50330 Dec  7 02:41 access_log-20141207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    36365 Dec 13 21:45 access_log-20141214
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 May 16  2014 books
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     5624 Dec 16 03:53 error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    97959 Nov 23 03:37 error_log-20141123
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   173890 Nov 30 03:47 error_log-20141130
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    21983 Dec  7 03:27 error_log-20141207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    38727 Dec 14 03:06 error_log-20141214
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     4096 Apr 24  2014 logs
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        0 May 18  2014 rewrite.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  7966502 Apr 27  2014 rewrite.log-20140427
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 37921419 May  4  2014 rewrite.log-20140504
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12590273 May 11  2014 rewrite.log-20140511
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8796765 May 16  2014 rewrite.log-20140518
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    51287 Dec 16 06:51 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    62385 Nov 23 03:28 ssl_access_log-20141123
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    79177 Nov 30 02:56 ssl_access_log-20141130
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    95657 Dec  6 15:13 ssl_access_log-20141207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    49738 Dec 13 16:38 ssl_access_log-20141214
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     1058 Dec 16 06:51 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    43297 Nov 23 03:28 ssl_error_log-20141123
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    33154 Nov 30 02:56 ssl_error_log-20141130
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     9721 Dec  6 14:31 ssl_error_log-20141207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     6108 Dec 13 11:08 ssl_error_log-20141214
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    57674 Dec 16 06:51 ssl_request_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    72020 Nov 23 03:28 ssl_request_log-20141123
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    92053 Nov 30 02:56 ssl_request_log-20141130
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   108199 Dec  6 15:13 ssl_request_log-20141207
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    57024 Dec 13 16:38 ssl_request_log-20141214
[root@devserver httpd]# cd bo*
[root@devserver books]# ls -l
total 456804
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  54836909 Dec 16 06:46 access.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   2606538 Dec 16 06:46 error.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  24019894 Dec 16 06:46 forwarded.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  54836909 Dec 16 06:46 log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 331438747 Dec 16 06:46 rewrite
[root@devserver books]#
```

Comment: `man logrotate`

Comment: @JennyD.  Thank you.  I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log rotation in RHEL and RHEL-alike systems is handled by a scheduled nightly job called "logrotate". The configuration of logrotate is in /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/*.conf,

The manpage for logrotate is at http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate and includes sample config files. You would need to add your custom log files to the logrotate configuration file.

If you need to archive log files off-box, you can put your script (possibly just a command to ftp / scp / NDM) into a `postrotate` block

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your logs to your preferred logrotating program:

> CustomLog file|pipe format|nickname [env=[!]environment-variable]

See [piped logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped) for more information on this, it's very versatile.